# Eval & AppSettings in the same expression?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, expression, appsettings

This is my mark up :

```
<asp:GroupRadioButton ID="GroupRadioButtonYes" runat="server" Text='<%$Resources:RATResource,YesHeader%>'
Value='<%#Eval("MLTFQuestionId","{0}_1") %>' GroupName='<%#Eval("MLTFQuestionId")%>' 
Visible='<%# (int)Eval("MLTFAnswerTypeId") == 1 %>'
class="GroupSelection" />
```

I want the number "1" to be driven from appsettings.

This obviously wont work

```
Visible='<%# (int)Eval("MLTFAnswerTypeId") == $ AppSettings: SingleSelect %>
```

Is it possible to have AppSettings and Eval in the same expression ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you try out like this

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
     Text='<%# getDAta() %>'></asp:Label>
```

codebehind

```
public string getDAta(0
{
  return "MLTFAnswerTypeId" + appsettingdatayouwant;
}
```